# set a full-bound legend of figure and the problem with non discrete x value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I`d like to have a multiline figure with a dataframe.

### Original data is as following:

```
from numpy.random import randn
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Years']=range(1995,2013)
np.random.seed(0)
df['Goverment']=randn(len(df.Years))
df['Household']=randn(len(df.Years))
df['Corporate']=randn(len(df.Years))
print(df)
```

and I want to set the legend along fully the bound pf figure box. I referred to the answer of [@Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)  but this problem hasn`t been solved.

### For plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(df.Years, df.Government,ls='--',label='Goverment',color='black')
ax.plot(df.Years,df.Household,ls=':',label='Household',color='black')
ax.plot(df.Years,df.Corporate,ls='-',label='Corporate',color='black')
plt.xlabel("common X")

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0 + box.height * 0.1,
                 box.width, box.height * 1])

# Put a legend below current axis
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1),borderaxespad=1,mode='expand',ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

and the following is my result. Apparently the **`mode='expand'`** doesn`t work here.
[image]

**My questions are:**
 1. Why the values on X axis are not integral but floats?
 2. How to expand the legend box into one line instrad fully along the bound of box?

---

#### The ideal legend box should be:

[image]

Comment: `ax.legend` takes an `ncol` argument that will do this for you

Comment: Copying the last section of Joe's answer that you link to gives the desired output for the legend. You are using slightly different values and therefore get a slightly different result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is indeed that you use the `mode='expand'`. Now this will tell the legend to expand in its bounding box. However the bounding box has no extent, it is a single point. The legend will hence expand inside a zero-width box and hence become shrunk to zero width itself.

The solution is to specify a bounding box with 4 coordinates (i.e. a true box). In principle this should also be explained in [my answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317). So here we would use axes coordinates for the `bbox_transform` and make the box one unit in axes coordinates wide.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2, top=0.95)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in range(5):
    line, = ax.plot(x, i * x, label='$y = %ix$'%i)

# Put a legend below current axis
ax.legend(loc="upper center", mode='expand',
          bbox_to_anchor=(0,-0.2,1,.1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes,
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]